# Using Matlab Parfor with 'Eval'

Tags: matlab, for-loop, parallel-processing

I am trying to execute a parfor loop within a parent script for Matlab.

I want to calculate the implied volatility of an option price, and then create a new column within a preexisting dataset with the results.

```
   load('/home/arreat/Casino/names.mat')
```

name = char(names(i))

```
%Loop over n rows to populate columns in dataset named using variable 'name(i)'

rows = eval(['length(',name,')'])

    parfor n=[1:rows]

%Calculate implied volatility using blsimpv(Price, Strike, Rate, Time, Value, Limit,Yield, Tolerance, Class)
BidIV = blsimpv(eval([name,'.UnderlyingPrice(n)']),...
eval([name,'.Strike(n)']),...
RiskFree/100,...
eval([name,'.Lifespan(n)'])/252,...
eval([name,'.Bid(n)'])+.01,...
10,...
0,...
1e-15,...
eval([name,'.Type(n)'])...
 )
eval([name,'.BidIV(n,1) = double(BidIV);']);


%Loop and add implied volatility (BidIV) to a column with n number of
%rows. 

end
```

The problem arises with the 'eval()' calculation in the parfor loop. Mathworks suggested that I should turn the whole script into a function, and then call the function within the parfor loop.

While I work on this, any ideas?

Comment: So, what is the problem? Getting rid of eval?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get rid of eval within the parfor loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `eval` all the time, you can call it once outside the loop, e.g. `data = eval(name)`, and then use `data.Strike` etc inside the `parfor` loop.

To avoid calling `eval` at all, do the following:

```
 %# load mat-file contents into structure allData, where 
 %# each variable becomes a field
 allData = load('/home/arreat/Casino/names.mat');
 data = allData.(name);
```

Comment: Okay, I tried implementing this approach, but I keep getting this error: 

"Attempt to reference field of non-structure array"

Comment: load('/home/arreat/Casino/names.mat');

      %names.mat is a (2853 X 1 cell);

i = 1;

name = char(names(i));

rows = eval(['length(',name,')']);

named = eval('name');


    parfor n=[1:rows];



BidIV(n,1) = blsimpv(named.UnderlyingPrice(n),...

named.Strike(n),...

RiskFree/100,...

named.Lifespan(n)/252,...

named.Bid(n)+.01,...

10,...

0,...

1e-15,...

named.Type(n)...

 );

    end;

 

This is the code

Comment: I solved it using your approach, 

Many thanks.

Ben